# Can't install Wine on Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I have run through the steps posted on various websites a dozen times and I keep getting the same error. So I added the key, and the repo, here it is in my /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

But then after an apt update, I attempt to install Wine 6.0 with the following command, and it errors out every time. The steps online that mention this issue all say it happens if you have the wrong repo added, but I am on focal so that should be correct?

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: why don't you just `sudo apt install wine64`?

Comment: I want to install wine 6, and running that command attempts to install wine 5, and it also errors out saying I have held broken packages unfortunately.

Comment: For the broken packages, try this http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/ .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)